# PHP curl_setopt() CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION

Tags: php, curl

i see in the [curl_setopt() documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) that you can set a callback function to display the progress of a curl_exec. There's not much said on how the callback function is used. Does anyone know? I'd just like to output the percentage of the file which has been downloaded to STDOUT. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

This is how the callback looks in C:

```
typedef int (*curl_progress_callback)(void *clientp,
                                      double dltotal,
                                      double dlnow,
                                      double ultotal,
                                      double ulnow);
```

Probably in PHP it should look like

```
curl_progress_callback($clientp, $dltotal, $dlnow, $ultotal, $ulnow)
```

I suppose that dl stands for download and ul for upload.

Answer (score 2):

You get a full example on the curl website at:

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curlgtk.html

More complete PHP answer here:
[cURL Download Progress in PHP not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939029/curl-download-progress-in-php-not-working)