# Simple process bar for copy file server to servera

Tags: php, file

I want to make a process bar that will show the uploading percentage & data size for server to server file transfer. I want to use this in this function:

```
<?php
function download_pretending($url,$user_agent) {
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);   
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   set_time_limit(3000); # 5 minutes for PHP
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3000); # and also for CURL   
   $result =base64_encode(curl_exec ($ch));
   curl_close ($ch);
   if(!$handle = fopen(basename($url), 'w+'))
   {
       echo "Cannot open file ".basename($url);
         exit;
   }
    if (fwrite($handle, $result) === FALSE) {
        echo "Cannot write to file ".basename($url);
        exit;
    }
     echo "Compleated ".basename($url);

   fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Please help me & thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION. Theres some info on it here: [PHP curl_setopt() CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214636/php-curl-setopt-curlopt-progressfunction) and here: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curlgtk.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would you please help me to do it for me ? I can't understand from your link.