# PHP CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION add extra custom parameter to function

Tags: php, curl

I was wondering if it is possible to add an custom parameter to the function called when using

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, array($this, 'progressFunction'));
```

so the function signature would look like

```
private function progressFunction($clientp, $dltotal, $dlnow, $ultotal, $ulnow, $myCustomParameter) { }
```

instead of

```
private function progressFunction($clientp, $dltotal, $dlnow, $ultotal, $ulnow) { }
```

Thanks.

Comment: You know the progress function only takes three parameters to being with right (curl resource, file descriptor resource, and length)?  This doesn't seem to match up with your proposed function signature at all.

Comment: according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214636/php-curl-setopt-curlopt-progressfunction it's correct this way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok this is strictly a suggestion and i will put it as an answer because i think it may work;

Php supports anonymous functions so you can pass it like so:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, function ($clientp, $dltotal, $dlnow, $ultotal, $ulnow) {

});
```

Now the trick is to pass your parameters using the `use` so:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, function (...) use ($myCustomParameter) {
    // Your code
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunatly doing so produces the following error: "Fatal error: Multiple access type modifiers are not allowed"

Comment: @xorinzor: Did you literally type `"..."` or did you replace it with the parameter list?

Comment: No I replaced it with the parameter list

Comment: hmm, I didn't include the $myCustomParameter in the parameter list though, that seems to have solved that error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Inside a PHP class, you can pass additional arguments like `$statusName` to another function as shown here:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, function ($resource, $downloadSize, $downloaded, $uploadSize, $uploaded) use ($statusName) {
    $this->progress($resource, $downloadSize, $downloaded, $uploadSize, $uploaded, $statusName);
});
```

Then your dedicated progress function doesn't uglify the code even more than it is:

```
private function progress($resource, $downloadSize, $downloaded, $uploadSize, $uploaded, $statusName="curl_download_status")
{
    // emit the progress    
    Cache::put($statusName, [
        'resource' => $resource,
        'download_size' => $downloadSize,
        'downloaded' => $downloaded,
        'upload_size' => $uploadSize,
        'uploaded' => $uploaded
    ], 10);

}
```